# Not able to change colours in curses on windows

Tags: python, windows, colors, ncurses, curses

I am using curses on windows from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses using 32 bit build for Python 3.4

It's been working really well so far except for the colours. It reports that it can change colours, but when trying to actually change the colours, nothing happens. Is this a limitation of curses for windows or a problem with my code?

```
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    curses.start_color()
    stdscr.addstr("Can Change Color? %s\n" % str(curses.can_change_color()))
    for i in range(0, curses.COLORS):
        curses.init_color(i, 1000, 0, 0)
        curses.init_pair(i + 1, i, 0)
    try:
        for i in range(0, 255):
            stdscr.addstr(str(i), curses.color_pair(i))
    except curses.ERR:
        pass
    stdscr.getch()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

In this, it reports that it can change colours, but when trying to set every colour to red (as a test), they all stay default.

Comment: Did you try to replace the `pass` so that it `print`s some exception information? Maybe `curses` is getting an error when trying to write using a color and you are hiding it (in this case it may be a limitation of the underlying C library or of the terminal itself).

Comment: @Bakuriu No exceptions, I think it's a limitation of PDCurses. No idea why it returns that it can change colours however.

Ideally I would like to change the version of PDCurses that the linked curses uses to the SDL version, but I have no idea how that is even using PDCurses.

Comment: PDCurses for Win32 console can indeed change colors, however the method is apparently broken on more recent versions of Windows. As for the SDL version, it's a drop-in replacement if you happen to be using the DLL build of the Win32 console version. It just renders the text using SDL instead of console calls.

Comment: @William I would use the SDL version, but the curses linked doesn't appear to use a pdcurses.dll as far as I can tell. So I can't replace it.

Comment: Found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855667/python-curses-not-displaying-colors-whereas-c-ncurses-works-fine) at last! I know its quite a while since you asked this, but in case anyone is still finding a solution, see the linked SO question.

Answer (score 4):

I know its been quite a while since you asked this question, but since this is one of the first hits for a google search like "python curses color issues", I thought I may as well answer this.

This [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27855733/849365) contains the exact solution you are looking for. You just don't call `curses.color_pair(i)` directly, but you have to define those pairs first:

```
stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.start_color()
curses.use_default_colors()
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
stdscr.addstr( "Pretty text", curses.color_pair(1) )
stdscr.refresh()
```

The above code will display the word "Pretty text" in red color and white background (but make sure that the console supports coloring by calling `curses.has_colors()` first.