# Python curses not displaying colors, whereas C ncurses works fine

Tags: python, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I can't seem to get the Python curses module to display colors, whereas the ncurses C library works fine. Here is a simple script that should work:

```
import curses

def main(stdscr):

  if not curses.has_colors(): raise
  stdscr.addstr("Hello world\n", curses.color_pair(curses.COLOR_RED))
  stdscr.addstr("Press any key to exit.\n")
  stdscr.refresh()
  while stdscr.getch() == -1: pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
  curses.wrapper(main)
```

I can only see "Press any key to exit.". I know "Hello world" is being written because of the new line, but I can't see the text. I attempted various color pairs, but only 0, i.e. white, works.

Not using the wrapper, i.e.

```
  stdscr = curses.initscr()
  curses.start_color()
  main(stdscr)
  curses.endwin()
```

Didn't help.

I tested it on XTerm(312), which has a black bg, and urxvt v9.20, which has a white one. I am on Debian jessie, using bash and Python 2.7.

I ran an old C script I had that uses ncurses and it displays colors nicely, so I assume either I'm doing something wrong or there's something wrong with the python library. I downloaded a package called colortest-python and it was able to display color too, although it doesn't use curses to do so (only to test if the terminal is capable of displaying colors).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to add the following lines at the beginning to initialize colors

```
curses.start_color()
curses.use_default_colors()
```

You then need o initialize color pairs with

```
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
```

This will initialize the first pair to red foreground and white background for example.
 After that you use the int value you pass as the first arg in the function instead of curses.COLORS in curses.color_pair() and the colors will appear properly.

Comment: Didn't help. [Full script](http://pastebin.com/70PJJN81). Other color pairs don't seem to work either

Comment: what outputs curses.has_colors()?

Comment: Oh well now i get it, you don't use colors directly, you need to declare a pair with curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_WHITE) and then use the int value you use in the first arg in curses.color_pair(1). That way should work

Comment: That worked out, but shouldn't those color pairs be initialized by the wrapper? Anyway, you can add it as the answer so I can accept it, if you want.

Comment: Looks like you have to do it by yourself as well